# Call forwarding / Recording / Messaging not working

Tags: twilio, webhooks, bin, forwarding, call-flow

**Hi guys.**
I am not understanding how to set up a call/sms forwarding and recording.
I have tried whit flows. I can see the inbound call, but there is no forwarding and no recording.
I am trying to forward to a +972 phone number, could this be a problem?

**My goal is simple - I wish the call be immediately recorded and forwarded. Same goes for SMS. Nothing complicated.
**
Thanks.

tried setting up bins and flows. Nothing seemed to work.

Comment: I don't think you can record a forwarded call. You'd need to conference the two together, I think: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference

Comment: I have 0 coding skills.. Would it be too much to ask the code from you?

Comment: It would be too much to ask, yes. You may want to hire someone to implement this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can record an inbound call or an outbound call using the [Dial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial?code-sample=code-set-dual-channel-recording-on-dial&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=4.x) verb with a [record](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial?code-sample=code-set-dual-channel-recording-on-dial&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=4.x#record) attribute in a [Twiml Bins](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/twiml-bins) (zero coding required) or by following this [Twilio Studio walk-through](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-forward-calls) (zero coding required).

Here is the Twiml to record a call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial record="record-from-ringing">
        <Number>+15558675310</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

If for some reason you cannot record or forward a call it could be due to a [limitation with a free/trial plan](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036052753-Twilio-Free-Trial-Limitations).

Twilio also makes this resource available ["Legal Considerations with Recording Voice and Video Communications"](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011522553-Legal-Considerations-with-Recording-Voice-and-Video-Communications).

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. And what would the SMS forwarding code be?

Comment: For SMS, it is similar. This page has a tutorial showing how to use Twiml Bins and Twilio Studio: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134287-Forwarding-SMS-messages-to-another-phone-number.